# LVM striping bottleneck

Tags: lvm, ext3

So, I have a server with a 3.5TB mysql database with innodb file for each table.  It has 24 2.5" 10K HDs in 4 disk RAID 10 groups attached as 1TB datastores via vmware ESXi. All 6 are LVM striped into one 6TB ext3 disk

Right now, I'm doing a

```
sudo e2fsck -f /dev/vg1/lv1
```

before a

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/vg1/lv1
```

and here's the results of iostat -x 5:

```
Device:         rrqm/s   wrqm/s     r/s     w/s   rsec/s   wsec/s avgrq-sz avgqu-sz   await  svctm  %util
sda               0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
sdb               0.00     0.00   33.40    0.00   267.20     0.00     8.00     0.17    5.15   5.15  17.20
sdc               0.00     0.00   36.20    0.00   289.60     0.00     8.00     0.14    3.76   3.76  13.60
sdd               0.00     0.00   33.20    0.00   265.60     0.00     8.00     0.14    4.28   4.28  14.20
sde               0.00     0.00   35.80    0.00   286.40     0.00     8.00     0.18    5.14   5.14  18.40
sdf               0.60     0.00   32.80    0.00   267.20     0.00     8.15     0.18    5.37   5.37  17.60
sdg               0.00     0.00   35.60    0.00   284.80     0.00     8.00     0.19    5.22   5.22  18.60
dm-0              0.00     0.00  207.60    0.00  1660.80     0.00     8.00     1.00    4.80   4.80  99.60
dm-1              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
dm-2              0.00     0.00    0.00    0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00     0.00    0.00   0.00   0.00
```

I've looked through the other posts on here and Google about LVM performance and none of them really give me enough info to diagnose if LVM could be bottlenecking the IO of the disks.  Tho, here it appears that dm-0 is maxing out in %util while the actual disks %util are all in their teens.

Is there something I could do to fix this? Stripe twice so that it is RAID 1000 instead of my RAID 100?  Does iostat just report wrongly for LVM?

Comment: Just a hint when looking for information. LVM is just a wrapper on top of device-mapper and once LVM prepared the device-mapper `dm-0` device, you can say that LVM is kind of out of the picture. So if you are looking for performance issues, you may want to focus on device-mapper instead of LVM.

Answer (score 1):

I finished this many months ago, but here is what I did:

For the e2fsck issue on a large disk that needs to go back online quickly, just skip it.  Since resize2fs forces a e2fsck if the disk isn't mounted, just leave it mounted and let resize2fs resize the lvm partition online.

As for the device-mapper bottleneck issue, iostat seems to not be aware that the partition is stripped (adding the %utils up is 99.3%) and [a post on unix.stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7122/does-lvm-impact-performance) assured me that lvm/dm don't have an impact on performance (besides during a lvm disk snapshot, but you should use [xtrabackup](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/) with --throttle=IOPS for mysql backups anyway).